# Can't access buttons from Form_Load in event handler

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three buttons in Form_Load, to every button I give size, location and text.
When I click one of the buttons a new button appears, which should take me to the first screen with the three original buttons. I clear the screen and add the buttons, but I get an error "the name 'button' does not exist in the current context". What can I do to have access to these buttons. Thanks.

Form_Load:

```
        Button play = new Button();
        Button howtoplay = new Button();
        Button puzzles = new Button();
        play.Size = new Size(175, 70);
        puzzles.Size = new Size(175, 70);
        howtoplay.Size = new Size(175, 70);
        play.Location = new Point((ClientRectangle.Right/2)-(play.Width/2), 135);
        puzzles.Location = new Point((ClientRectangle.Right / 2) - (play.Width / 2), 210);
        howtoplay.Location = new Point((ClientRectangle.Right / 2) - (play.Width / 2), 285);
        play.Text = "Play";
        howtoplay.Text = "How To Play";
        puzzles.Text = "Puzzles";
        Controls.Add(play);
        Controls.Add(howtoplay);
        Controls.Add(puzzles);
        howtoplay.Click += new EventHandler(howtoplay_click);
```

howtoplay_click:

```
            play.Hide();
            puzzles.Hide();
            howtoplay.Hide();
            Button backB = new Button();
            backB.Size = new Size(100, 50);
            backB.Location = new Point((ClientRectangle.Right - backB.Width - 10), (ClientRectangle.Bottom - backB.Height - 10));
            backB.Text = "Back";
            backB.Click += new EventHandler(Back_Click);
            Controls.Add(backB);
```

Back_Click:

```
        Controls.Clear();
        Controls.Add(play); //error
        Controls.Add(puzzles); //error
        Controls.Add(howtoplay); //error
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared buttons as local variables of `Form_Load` event handler method:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button play = new Button();
     Button howtoplay = new Button();
     Button puzzles = new Button();
     // ...
}
```

These variables are not available outside the method. You should use form fields instead:

```
// available in all instance methods of form
Button play;
Button howtoplay;
Button puzzles;

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     play = new Button();
     howtoplay = new Button();
     puzzles = new Button();
     // ...
}
```

Note: Usually you should manually create controls only when those controls should be added to your form dynamically at runtime. But you are creating controls in `Form_Load` event handler, so I suggest you use [*designer*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e06hs424%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to create controls. It will create a class field for each control and add appropriate initialization code. All you need to do is drag-and-drop control (buttons in this case) from toolbox to form and setup each control properties.

Comment: Yes I tried doing it, but when I add the buttons I get nothing, like there is no location, size or text. just empty screen.

Comment: @LiorAltshul make sure you don't have any other classes in `Form.cs` file. You can create new form from scratch and try to use designer with that form

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Are you sure that the Form_Load function is actually called? Double-click onto your form, to create an event handler for this event and write the code into the automatically created function.